# Access to fetch at 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' from origin 'https://gmbexample-f23ef.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to get the refresh token but when i am trying to get using this https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token and here is my code to get the refresh token i am using google one-tap sign in but i am unable to get the refresh token and getting this error

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' from origin 'https://gmbexample.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token net::ERR_FAILED

> error TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Infinity</h2>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="xxxx"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        const config = {
          scope:
            "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
          client_id: "xxxx",
          immediate: true,
          response_type: "code",
        };

        gapi.auth2.authorize(config, async function (response) {
          // var requestOptions = {
          //   method: "GET",
          //   redirect: "follow",
          // };
          console.log(response.code);
          retrieveToken(response.code);

          let myHeaders = new Headers();
          myHeaders.append("code", response.code);
          myHeaders.append("client_id", "xxxx");
          myHeaders.append("client_secret", "xxxxxx");
          myHeaders.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
          myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
          console.log(myHeaders);
          var requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: "follow",
          };

          fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));

          // var idToken = response.id_token;
          // await db.collection("Accounts").add(response);
          // fetch(
          //   `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=${response.access_token}`,
          //   requestOptions
          // )
          //   .then((response) => response.text())
          //   .then((result) => console.log(result))
          //   .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        });
      }
      function retrieveToken(code) {
        // console.log(code);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Client sided languages use implicit flow oauth2 which due to security concerns will not return a refresh token.  Switch to a server sided language.

Comment: @DaImTo but in the documentation, they have implemented using javascript and HTML and i am also running on the firebase. and if i have to use a server-side language like nodejs then it will work? here is the documentation link https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/implement-oauth#offline-access

Comment: You should be fine with node.  Try digging around with this one if you can get the auth working in this sample just swap out the drive service with my business https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @DaImTo i am not able to get the refresh token with my above code?

Comment: if the above code is javascript as you have taged the question then no it is client sided you can not get a refresh token back

Comment: @DaImTo is ot possible to get the refresh token using the authorization code?

Comment: Yes you can get a refresh token from a authorization code when using a server sided programming language.  Not when using a client sided language which is running implicit flow.

Comment: can you explain how can i get that using nodejs?

Comment: Have you tried following https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs and altering it for the other api?

Comment: If you're using Firebase, they should have built-in support for Sign-in with Google. Otherwise, you'll need to either use a grant type for front-end applications, such as Implicit Grant, or you'll need to implement a web server for the `code` grant and to retrieve a refresh token. It may also be worth looking at a managed OAuth service like [Xkit](https://xkit.co) to avoid writing a web server.